# Windows Command line: how can I list all files in all folders without the location just a list of files

Tags: windows, file, cmd, command-line, directory

How can I within Windows command prompt list all files that are contained in that directory and all subdirectories but the list should only contain a list of files and not the directory location that each file is found in?

Example:
dir /d /s /b /q *.txt will get a list of all text files in all directories so I will end up with c:\example1.txt c:\folder1\example2.txt but I need only the list to show example1.txt example2.txt I hope my question is understandable. just a list of files not showing their paths?

Comment: recursively not possible with `dir`. Use a `for /r "startfolder" %a in (*.txt) do @echo %~nxa`. See `for /?` for more interesting modifiers.

Answer (score 2):

You can try with this command in PowerShell

```
 dir *.txt -r | % Name
```

From cmd you can execute like

```
PowerShell -Command "dir *.txt -r | % Name"
```

Comment: David Villalobos Thank you for your quick response. The cmd-line works perfectly just as I had desired.

Answer (score 0):

There can be used in a Windows command prompt window:

```
for /R %I in (*.txt) do @echo %~nxI
```

That results in searching **recursive** because of option `/R` in current directory and all its subdirectories for non-hidden files of which long or short 8.3 file name is matched by the wildcard pattern `*.txt`. Output is just the file name with extension.

Run in a command prompt window `for /?` to get output the help of the [Windows command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/windows-commands) **FOR**.

There can be used in a command prompt window also:

```
for /F "delims=" %I in ('dir *.txt /A-D /B /S 2^>nul') do @echo %~nxI
```

This command line starts in background one more `cmd.exe` with option `/c` to execute the command line enclosed in `'` appended as additional arguments. So there is executed in background:

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c dir *.txt /A-D /B /S 2>nul
```

The command **DIR** searches now

- in current directory and all its subdirectories because of option `/S`
- for just files because of option `/A-D` (all attributes except directory attribute) including also **hidden** files
- of which long or short 8.3 name is matched by the wildcard pattern `*.txt`.

There is output to handle **STDOUT** of background command process just the list of found file names in bare format because of option `/B` with full path because of option `/S`.

It is possible that **DIR** does not find any file system entry matched by the criteria which results in an error message output to handle **STDOUT**. This error message is redirected with `2>nul` to the device **NUL** to suppress it.

Read the Microsoft documentation about [Using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)) for an explanation of `2>nul`. The redirection operator `>` must be escaped with caret character `^` on **FOR** command line to be interpreted as literal character when Windows command interpreter processes this command line before executing command **FOR** which executes the embedded `dir` command line with using a separate command process started in background.

The output list of fully qualified file names is captured by `cmd.exe` being opened as Windows command prompt and processed by **FOR** after `cmd.exe` started in background closed itself. So it can take some time until there is something displayed in the command prompt window depending on how much file system entries must be searched for by the command **DIR** of background command process.

**FOR** would split up by default each line into substrings using normal space and horizontal tab as string delimiters. This line splitting behavior is not wanted here and therefore the option `delims=` is used to define an empty list of string delimiters to turn off the line splitting. So each file name is assigned one after the other to the specified loop variable `I`.

The command **ECHO** outputs finally the file name assigned to loop variable `I` with just name and extension.

Run in the command prompt window also `dir /?` for help on this internal command of the Windows Command Processor.